Why are survival models fit / plotted with the "staircase" instead of a smooth function?
I am relatively new to survival modeling.  I cannot find a text that fully explains why survival is treated differently than other regression models.
I think I understand how the model is modifying the hazard function, and this modification is applied to the data set itself to produce the plot.
I don't understand why the data is used as the basis for the plot/fit and not smooth curves.

This approach requires binning the data by year/week/day/etc. to produce the staircase.  That binning seems arbitrary.  Why not fit a continuous function of time to data with maximum likelihood (like in logistic regression).  It seems you wouldn't require any artificial binning and could deal with more precise values on the time axis.
The data set is just a sample of the population - why does it deserve to have so much specific control over how we visualize and interpret the results?  i.e. defining the breakpoints in the staircase and the base hazard.



no you have fundamentally misunderstood one survival method ( kaplan-meier), where the breakpoints are literally where a (rare) event happens ( so no binning). there are plenty of parametric survival methods that assume a smooth hazard rate

Thanks for the correction.  Survival models aren't covered in my stats textbooks, so I've been muddling through with terse & incomplete online material.  Am I correct that non-parametric methods have this staircase appearance built from the sample itself, and parametric methods are smooth fit curves?  And the non-parametric methods are those in the {survival} R package while parametric are elsewhere in {eha} and possibly in other packages I've yet to encounter?

{survival} has parametic methods too - in particular Accelerated Failure time Models see eg the survival vignette.  I realised after that Cox, perhaps the most famous survival model is also semi-parametric.  Another class of models is discrete time survival models, where you bin time and then use eg logistic regression for each period ( but obviously this is then discretised). arguably you can make the discretisation as fine as you want and make time (and functions of time) a continuous independent variable
